# reference or comparison

Tags: word-choice, nouns

Context: Country A has a much larger population than Country B. People of the two countries have similar habits to consume Product P. We know that the market size of Product P in Country B is 1 billion dollars a year, which is already big. Thus, we can infer that the market size of Product P in Country A must be very big and larger than 1 billion dollars a year.

So, which sentence is more correct?

- The market size of Country B **serves as a reference** to demonstrate the market size of Country A.
- The market size of Country B **serves as a comparison** to demonstrate the market size of Country A.

Comment: Reference is okay; benchmark is better

Comment: *The population-to-market ratio in Country B can serve as an [indicator](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/indicator) of that in Country A.*

Comment: benchmark, indicator, pointer, guide, frame of reference